# Fill a background with colour Python by taking specific column: slice indices error

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with Python to Take 'Revenue daily' column and make a colour on it if value is bigger/smaller then 'Daily budget'. Problem is somewhere in 'for j', error :slice indices must be integer or none    :

```
Example of table:
Column1(team)......      Column6(Daily BUDGET) Column7(REVENUE Daily)
a                               1000              1100
b                               1500              50
c                               50                (NULL)
```

Code:

```
for index, i in enumerate(soup.tbody.findAll('tr')[:-1]):
    for j in i.findAll('td')[2:df_data['REVENUE Daily'].iloc[index][0:7].strip()]: 
            if float(j.text.strip()) >= float(df_data['Daily BUDGET'].iloc[index][0:6].strip()):
                j.attrs['style'] = 'text-align: center; background-color: #D6FCE9;'
            else:
                j.attrs['style'] = 'text-align: center; background-color: #F2D6E1;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using slice on a list, you need to make sure that both the values(start and end) are integers or None or combination of both.

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
l_temp = l[start:end]
```

examples:-

```
l_temp = l[:]
l_temp = l[1:3]
l_temp = l[:3]
l_temp = l[2:]
```

In your case, replace

`for j in i.findAll('td')[2:df_data['REVENUE Daily'].iloc[index][0:7].strip()]`

by

`for j in i.findAll('td')[2:int(df_data['REVENUE Daily'].iloc[index][0:7].strip())]`

Because I am assuming that `end` value is some string as you have used `strip` on it :) .

Comment: Can you give post the exact error you are getting? It's just thet you need to make sure that `start` and `end` are integers everywhere.

Comment: No i get error: Invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Comment: What i want to do only that Column7(revenue daily) will have colour green if number is larger than column 6(budget) and red if that number is lower

Comment: Well thats the underlying logic. But unfortunately the code breaks before that :(. Can you print the value for `df_data['REVENUE Daily'].iloc[index][0:7].strip()`? I guess its an empty string. What exactly are you expecting here.  Please check its output and correct accordingly.